# Why does StackWalk64 return always true?

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, stack-trace

I tried to make my program dump and save its stack trace when crashes. I installed my own win32 SE handler with `_set_se_translator` and tried to dump the stack trace with `StackWalk64` and finally throw a C++ exception (which actually does the logging when caught).

The code looks like this:

```
...
_set_se_handlers(WIN32EXCEPTION::Win32ExceptionStuff);
...

void WIN32EXCEPTION::Win32ExceptionStuff(unsigned int Code, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* Info) // static
{
    STACKFRAME64 sf64;
    sf64.AddrPC.Offset     = Info->ContextRecord->Eip;
    sf64.AddrStack.Offset  = Info->ContextRecord->Esp;
    sf64.AddrFrame.Offset  = Info->ContextRecord->Ebp;
    sf64.AddrPC.Mode= sf64.AddrStack.Mode= sf64.AddrFrame.Mode= AddrModeFlat;
    while (StackWalk64(IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386,GetCurrentProcess(),GetCurrentThread(),
        &sf64,Info->ContextRecord,0,SymFunctionTableAccess64,SymGetModuleBase64,0))
    {
        //... Do something with the stack frames
    }
    throw WIN32EXCEPTION(/*...*/);
}
```

as I saw in some examples, but there is a problem: StackWalk64 always return true and that `while` loop becomes infinite. The StackWalk64 only repeats the same frame.

What is the problem, and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very similar to code I've got, and that does work. The only difference I can see is that my code uses ZeroMemory() to clear the STACKFRAME64 structure before populating any parts of it - this may be required.

Comment: You can do `STACKFRAME64 sf64 = {0};` to zero it out too.